# No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a SQL query and I have an array in one table and in that array I stores IDs and want to compare that array of IDs with another table to show data against that ids. when I run it gives me following error.

No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking.

Here is my query

```
select TagId
     , Name 
  from ctrData2.Tag
  Left 
  outer join ctrData2.CallDetail 
    On Tag.TagId = array(CallDetail.Tag)
 where CallDetail.ContactId = 'f9d4787a-f1ac-41af-97d8-ea324daad018'
```

this is how I store IDs in array in Tag Column

[image]

here is the other table from where I want to show data against these ids

[image]

Comment: what is the name of your schema?, is it ctrData2?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: @RahulKumar yes, schema name is ctrData2

Comment: @MarkRotteveel MYSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the default schema by below query first

> use ctrData2;

And run below query

```
select TagId, Name
from Tag, CallDetail
where CallDetail.ContactId = 'f9d4787a-f1ac-41af-97d8-ea324daad018' and LOCATE(Tag.TagId, CallDetail.Tag) > 0;
```

Comment: please try second approach

Comment: I don't know how to set default schema in MySQL Workbench

Comment: you mean like this use ctrData2 Select TagId...............?

Comment: use semicolon between two query. I mean like this use ctrData2; Select TagId...............

Comment: **Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION ctrData2.array does not exist** aaah new error :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217736/discussion-between-rahul-kumar-and-tayyab).